# Are these Class and Sequence UML models valid?

Tags: class, oop, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I'm doing a software engineering assignment to build a system of my interest and express it as UML models. It's quite fun, to be honest, but I am not sure the current class diagram is fit for 3-tier models? Any wrong representation, I will be happy to be roasted.

Oh, the system is the car parking spot sharing service that user can share their private parking spot when they are not using it. Or, a user with multiple parking spots may open a slot all time, earning more profits. I thought of the idea of HK's infamous scarcity of parking space.
[image]

[image]

Comment: At a first glance it looks ok. But the question as such is simply too broad. You will need more focus here.

Comment: Syntactically it is mostly ok, besides of the wrong return message arrows. Usually a return message is shown as dashed line with an open arrow head. You are using partly solid lines or filled heads.

Comment: Contentwise the sequence diagram needs severe rework. E.g., it mixes aspects of analysis with design, it includes several use cases, deals with several aspects.... Depending on what kind of assignment you are doing, these are severe failures.

Comment: @qwerty_so oh i didn't consider that.. my fault.

Comment: @sim I revised the return msg arrows. But should a sequence diagram contain only one  use-case?

Comment: An SD should (what the name says) have one sequence of messages and not the whole system. Create individual SDs for different (compicated) aspects/collaborations which need clarification.